# Blender Shader in OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to extract the Blender Shader and use them in OpenGL as vertex/fragment shaders (GLSL)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can if you use an addon, see  the BlenderArtists page [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?233186-Export-Materials-to-GLSL-Code). That page doesn't have the correct download link but you can get it [here](https://developer.blender.org/T28839).
From memory, this addon generates rather long and possibly unoptimised GLSL fragment code.

Comment: this is outdated, I would like to know if there is something recent working for this question

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept: compiling material nodes into GLSL shaders:
https://github.com/Bentschi/Blender-GLSL-translator

Also see: https://developer.blender.org/F151259