# Does a model exporter embedding materials as GLSL scripts exist?

Tags: materials, export, shaders, file-format, opengl

as described in [Blender Shader in OpenGL/GLSL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31172/blender-shader-in-opengl-glsl), it is possible to export the (unoptimized) GLSL code generated by Blender for a given material.

Since the viewport can use such GLSL for real-time shading, my understanding is that Blender could be used to fully design and preview assets for real-time applications, without restricting materials to existing shaders/parameters (since nodes can be used to design a large variety of GLSL-exportable materials).

But exporting GLSL shaders manually for each material, then exporting geometries, and finally associating them in the final render engine does not seem like an efficient workflow.

So I was wondering if there exists any Blender model exporter (whatever file format it exports to) that does export generated GLSL code alongside geometries?

Regards.

Comment: As an illustration, [this material setup](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31402/gold-foil-material-for-export) would benefit from such an export (should the target engine accept GLSL shaders).

Comment: I'm sorry, but as far as I am aware it is impossible to export materials with your model. You will have to export GLSL separately to the model. Using Blender as a shader editor would be cool, and is something I would want to do.

Comment: The Blend4Web addon does this and more.

Comment: @Amziraro my understanding is that easier design of GLSL shaders using Blender nodes will be a byproduct of the [viewport improvements effort](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-viewport/2015-June/000000.html).

Comment: @MarcClintDion Indeed, the Blend4Web documentation states that "[All shaders used in the engine are processed by a compilator](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/developers_advanced.html#index-0)", but that seem rather vague. Are Blender-generated GLSL shaders  exported in the intermediary json representation of Blend4Web assets?

Comment: @MarcClintDion I see that [most material nodes are supported by the engine](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/node_materials.html), which is very encouraging. But do you know whether Blender-generated GLSL is  exported in the intermediary json representation of Blend4Web assets, or if the nodes structure is?

Comment: There is lots of docs and you can ask a rep from the team question directly on the following thread.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?333214-Blend4Web-a-3D-web-framework-for-Blender-artists

Comment: The following Addon shows how to export a custom model format for C/OpenGL(no GLSL) http://ksolek.fm.interiowo.pl/Blender/ The link at the bottom of the page named "NEW OpenGL Blender Export Addon Blender 2.63" works for recent versions of Blender and is easy to follow if you have experience in this area.  Printing the materials in a way that you can use will require you to understand GLSL and this is far outside the scope of this site but the Blend4Web Addon may give you enough clues on how to get started.

Comment: @MarcClintDion thanks for the last link, but it only export geometries and textures to fixed-pipeline, old-school OpenGL C code. Exporting (most) materials as GLSL is already provided by an existing plug-in, as linked from my question. What I am wondering is: can the geometry and GLSL shaders be exported as a coherent whole, to ease workflow?

Comment: @MarcClintDion Blend4Web definitely goes in the direction I am asking, even if is is exporting to WebGL + JavaScript. I am more interested by an exporter to a neutral file format I could import to any engine. Anyway, could you please write an answer in the spirit of your comment, so that I could accept it?

Comment: seems it's duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685413/exporting-glsl-from-blender

Answer (score 1):

blender can export GLTF, which supports embedding PBR material in your export.

However it seems you are looking for exporting custom shaders. This should be doable with USD.

USD is designed to export scene data across software, and has shader export support.

You can find more info here, hopefully this helps you finding the answer https://developer.blender.org/tag/usd/